Excessive slowness in aspx saves for devexpress web v20.1 on visual studio 2022
We have a very annoying problem with saving the aspxes that have devexpress web in version 20.1 on visual studio 2022.
Since we moved from Visual Studio 2019 to Visual Studio 2022 we have found that saving ASPXs with DeveXpress components inside are very slow.
As soon as we make any type of change to the file, the saving time is very long (several seconds) compared to the lightning-fast saves we were used to.
Can you tell us how we can solve the problem? because we tried different solutions but none of them worked!
Thank you so much.

Do note you are jumping into the world of x64 bit computing. Keep in mind that vs2022 is the FIRST version of VS that is x64 bit computing. You don't mention how much ram, what kind of disk drives and CPU your computers have. Having stated above, any good decent spec'ed out computer should be able to run vs2022, but given that vs2022 is now a x64 bit version, and is first version to run as x64 bits, then like the last 35+ years of our industry, then jumping to the v-next of ANY software will take more ram, load slower, and use more CPU to function.  Does VS run ok without DeveExpress tools?
